# Why does 'top' show three roslaunch processes?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whenever I use `roslaunch` to launch a launchfile (ha :)), the output of `top` (or `htop`) shows three `roslaunch` processes. One that is the parent of all nodes, and two more that have no children.

I could probably try to read the source of roslaunch, but does anyone here have any idea what those extra two are doing there? I've never seen more than 2, so it does not seem related to the number of nodes in the graph.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41632/why-does-%27top%27-show-three-roslaunch-processes?/) by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2012-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're seeing are multiple threads in roslaunch. If you want to hide user threads in htop, you can type 'H'.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-08-16**:
Seems like your right. Thanks.